# how to change the data of an array without losing initial data in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7, matrix

I am trying to execute this python code below, and i see the data of the 2-d array "grid" , is changing after the fourth print statement. I don't understand why it is changing . can anybody help me please?

```
print(grid)
for i in range(len(grid)):
    grid[i]=list(grid[i])
print(grid)
set1=grid
print(grid)

for i in range(len(set1)):
    for j in range(len(set1[i])):
        set1[i][j]='O'
print(grid)
```

debug output:

```
['.......', '...O...', '....O..', '.......', 'OO.....', 'OO.....']
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Also, what python version are you using?

Comment: you need to use deepcopy

Comment: i want to loop through the grid, and when i encounter "O" in a position, i want to change the values of elements in that particular position in the array  "set1", which has dimensions of the grid, but is filled with "O"s.

Comment: you need to assign the copy of `gird` to `set1`

Comment: @deadshot yes! thanks a lot!! I am new to programming.. Sorry if i looked ridiculous .. And this is my first question on stack  overflow  :)